# Connecting to two +5V sources on same rail to increase current for a eurorack USB power module

Tags: power-supply, parallel

I'm very new to electronics and have basically no practical knowledge. I am hoping to modify a USB power eurorack module to to have more available current by connecting to two +5V sources on the power supply.

1. Would connecting to both of these actually increase the current available?
2. Is there some circuitry I need to be able to connect these in parallel? Or is it as simple as using some Y cables?

### Power Supply

The euroack power supply has two 5V connection points, labelled as E on the image below and highlighted in yellow in the schematic. (I don't really know what "rail" means, but I believe both of these connect to the same 5V rail).

[image]

[image]

### USB module

The USB module has soldered in wires labelled +5V and ground.
[image]

Comment: Please read the manual for the device to see if both 5 volts and their respective ground connections can be put in parallel.